# What factors make training (fit()) extremely slow for training set of 5,000?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I am running a fit() using a training set of about 5,000 rows, using LogisticRegression as the classifier. I am using CrossValidator and a parameter grid (maybe around 480 combinations in total, assuming each parameter is tried alongside all  combinations of the other parameters)

This is running locally ("local[*]" -- so all available cores should be used), and is assigned 12GB of RAM. The training set is small compared to what we will eventually have.

This is running for days -- not what I expected. Can someone provide some tips / explanation of the main areas that might affect this performance?

I'd rather not set up Spark as a cluster unless strictly necessary. I would have thought this was not a monumental task.

An example of the param grid:

```
return new ParamGridBuilder()
    .addGrid(classifier.regParam(), new double[]{0.0, 0.1, 0.01, .3, .9})
    .addGrid(classifier.fitIntercept())
    .addGrid(classifier.maxIter(), new int[]{10, 20, 100}) 
    .addGrid(classifier.elasticNetParam(), new double[]{.8, .003}) 
    .addGrid(classifier.threshold(), new double[]{0.0, .03, 0.5, 1.0})
    .addGrid(classifier.standardization());
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 480 models has to be trained and tested..  This is huge amount of work.

I suggest yo do some manual exploration to determine where to do GridSearch..

For instance, you could validate that fitIntercept is good or not just once (instead of 240 times with one value and 240 times with othe other value)

Same thing with standardization..

Some of theses parameters are black/white decision to make.